# Can I make an appeal to my UK Visa decision, denied after marriage and child where previously approved single

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens

I visited the UK last year on 12 June 2015 and returned 16 June 2015. In last year's visa application, I stated that I was single because I wasn't married at that time. I did have a girlfriend and she was pregnant at that time. I am a Ghanaian living in Italy.

This year on February 13th, 2016, we got married. After our marriage I wanted us to go to the UK for the Easter holidays to visit. I submitted a new application last month on February 25th and I stated that am married and will  travel with my wife and my ten month old baby girl.

They refused us on March 9th because they said in my previous application I stated that I was single. My supporting documents included our marriage certificate, bank statement with amount of 12,500 euros, pay slips, working contract, tax cud, letter from my company, family status, tenancy agreement, and many more but they have refused me and my family.

So what can I do now to appeal the visa decision?

Comment: Please post a copy of your full refusal notice (after redacting any personal information).

Comment: Doesn't sound right...  Did the whole family apply together? Was everyone refused? Please scan in your refusal notice, and use 'Paint' to blacken out personal information and upload it into your question as an image.

Comment: What were the options on the question about marriage? Was it just marital status, or were you expected to also declare other family relationships, like being the father of a child?

Comment: @DJClayworth, the likelihood here is that the OP isn't giving the whole story. People get married and it is a routine event.  Wait until the OP uploads the notice (or abandons the question altogether).